# AngularJS - Handling empty Params

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I'm using UI-Router and all is working great but I'd like to prevent the possibility that someone could access a page with empty Params. Is there a "best" method for preventing something like... '/person//info' where it would normally expect an id for the person like '/person/23/info'. My setup is as follows...

```
.state('person',{
        abstract:true,
        url:'/:id/',
        templateUrl: '/assets/components/views/person.html',
        controller: function($stateParams){
          console.log($stateParams.id);
        }
      })
```

The reason this is a real pain is because if you hit the path '/person//info', it will redirect to /person/info essentially breaking the app

Comment: url:'/:id/info' seems like the correct way to go, if you want a match on '/:id/info'. Also, read this stuff: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/108

Comment: In my controllers I validate the route parameters first thing and redirect to some neutral page if not valid.